# javascript repeatedly change document background color

Tags: javascript

```
colors = new           Array("red","orange","blue","purple","yellow","brown","green","grey")

var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor(){
document.body.bgColor=colors[colorIndex]
 colorIndex = (colorIndex+1)%8)


}

 function startColorChange(){

 setInterval("changeColor()",1000)
}
window.onload = startColorChange
console.log(colors.length);
```

Its code about changing the document background color on every 1 sec repeatedly. 
  variable colorIndex increments each time and show output by changing different colors.but question iscolorIndex= (colorIndex+1)%8. first time its value is 0 so red color would be shown but in next round its will value would become 0.125 then how orange color can show even its index is clearly 1 not 0.125 similarly so on every times index is not increasing from 0 to 1,2,3,4,5... then how color is changing respectively.

Comment: why `parseInt`? you are working with integers, anyway.

Comment: [`var colors = ["red", "orange", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "brown", "green", "grey"],
    colorIndex = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    document.body.bgColor = colors[++colorIndex % colors.length];
}, 1000);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n400pfxh/1)

Comment: Try to read attentively what is the `%` operator http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp It is not the simple division

Comment: @MysterX thx modulus is making me worry.

Answer (score 2):

You code is working fine if you delete the last parentesis:

```
colorIndex = (colorIndex+1)%8)
//                          ^^^
```

The lower proposal has a more cleaned code.

```js
var colors = ["red", "orange", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "brown", "green", "grey"],
    colorIndex = 0;

function changeColor() {
    document.body.bgColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length;
}

function startColorChange() {
    setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
}

window.onload = startColorChange;
```